# How do I install ygraph for fortran?

Tags: software-installation, fortran

So I have just started using Ubuntu and need to use fortran for a project I am working on. I’ve been told to install ygraph, but when I try to by using

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ygraph
```

it can’t find ‘ygraph’

I was given the advice to install the compiled code, but I honestly know nothing abut computers and I can’t find what this means from google.

Please help, and don’t worry about ‘over explaining’ because I will need it.

Comment: The `ygraph` package was dropped from Ubuntu after 14.04 (six years ago), so a bit more information or direction from whomever told you to install ygraph would be very helpful to you. Open a Terminal and enter `apt search ygraph` for a list of the ygraph-related packages available for the Python, Texlive, and R languages...but that is merely supplementary information, not solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install ygraph open the terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Desktop/
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/y/ygraph/ygraph_0.16~cvs20090218-1.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./ygraph_0.16~cvs20090218-1.1_amd64.deb
```

These commands were tested on Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to work